# json_decode on result from mysql json_object not working

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to do a query on a table where I want to select some columns and some other columns as a nested json object, for example, I want to select the list of users with it's address as a nested object.

```
SELECT
    u.first_name, u.last_name, u.age, u.phone,
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'zip', a.zip,
        'address', a.address,
        'number', a.number,
        'city', a.city,
        'state', a.state
    ) as 'address'

FROM
    tb_user u,
    tb_user_address a

WHERE u.id_address = a.id
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        first_name: 'my name',
        last_name: 'my last name',
        ... // Some other fields
        address: {
            zip: '987',
            address: 'street name',
            ... // Some other fields
        }
    },
    {
        // Another user
    }
]
```

But when it returns, the `address` field is just a plain string, like this: `address: "{'zip': '987', 'address': 'street name', 'city': 'cityname', 'state'...};"` and only this field (the one using `JSON_OBJECT`) is returning like this, the others are ok.

When I return the result from the sql query, I'm doing like this:

```
$user_list = json_decode(json_encode($query_result), true);
```

But it also doesn't resolve the problem. Is there a way to turn that string into a valid json object?

Comment: ``SELECT JSON_OBJECT(...) as `address` FROM ...`` causes the fields inside the `JSON_OBJECT` call to be converted to a JSON string and returned as the `address` column. Your first name etc. aren't part of the `JSON_OBJECT` call and as such won't be in there.

Comment: _address field is just a plain string_ That's JSON, what did you think JSON was?

Comment: The MySQL driver has no idea what JSON is so you're left decoding it like that. If you use an ORM it can do that for you transparently, but otherwise you can't expect this to happen by magic alone.

Comment: I haven't used `JSON_OBJECT` before, but you can just wrap the whole thing up in a json_object so you can `json_decode` the entire row that is returned: `SELECT JSON_OBJECT(first_name, last_name, age, phone, JSON_OBJECT(<address fields)) FROM your table...`  Then `json_decode($query_result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the address JSON object in MySQL, so it gets returned as a string containing the JSON formatted data among the other columns.

You could do the following to convert it to a PHP array before JSON-encoding the entire result:

```
$user_list = array_map(
    function ($v) { return json_decode($v['address'], true); },
    $query_result
);
$user_list = json_encode($user_list);
```